# Using a method defined in another .dll

Tags: c++, dllexport

Development environmnet: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017.

I have the following methods defined in `api.h` and implemented in `api.cpp` then compiled into `api.dll`. Compilation also produced `api.lib`.

```
extern "C" int validate( int v_mode, char * data, int data_length );
```

I have created another different project. In that project I included `api.h`, and then from project settings, I added `api.lib` into additional libraries to link with as well as I set the additional libraries directory.

This project is super simple console application with which I will test the previously mentioned `validate` method.

```
#include "api.h"
int main() {
    char data[] ={1,2,3};
    validate(ValidationModes::Video,data,3);
}
```

I get the following error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol validate referenced in function main

Well as the compiler is telling it is linking error. After a bit of searching, I added `__declspec(dllexport)` to my `validate` method.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int validate( int v_mode, char * data, int data_length );
```

Then I could compile and run without any problems. My question is the following:

For any method, class, variable etc, which exists in `A.dll`, if I try to access those methods, classes, variables etc. from an outside source such as my test application, do I have to set them as `__declspec`?

I am fairly new to c++ development in Windows environment. I do not remember ever doing something similar to this when I was using g++. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you wanna use those "names" (function, variable, class, etc.) outside the DLL, you have to "export" them. Note that you only need to do that on Windows (where symbols are not exported from DLL by default). On Linux it's the opposite - all symbols are exported and you'd need to hide whatever you don't want to be exported.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is just like I suspected!

Comment: However, it looks quite troublesome for everything that I need to use I have to `export` them. Is there any way such that I can export whole library. as in the default behavior of Linux. Moreover, if I do not have access to the source code of the already compiled dll, then I will NOT be able to access those methods etc? Is that correct

Comment: Here you can find a lot of info on that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll?view=vs-2017. However, exporting all symbols is generally not a good idea, first of all it increases DLL load time, also you don't want all your symbols exposed to the world, maybe the function is just for your private use etc.

Comment: @ user3132457 Thanks for the the input!